# Adding counter to my Python Web Crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler

I've made a web crawler which gives a link and text from link for all sites in given addres it looks like this:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse
import mechanize

url = ["http://adbnews.com/area51"]


for u in url:
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    urls = [u]
    visited = [u]
    i = 0
    while i<len(urls):
        try:
            br.open(urls[0])
            urls.pop(0)

            for link in br.links():

                levelLinks = []
                linkText = [] 

                newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
                b1 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).hostname
                b2 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).path
                newurl = "http://"+b1+b2
                linkTxt = link.text
                linkText.append(linkTxt)
                levelLinks.append(newurl)


                if newurl not in visited and urlparse.urlparse(u).hostname in newurl:
                    urls.append(newurl)
                    visited.append(newurl)
                    #print newurl

                    #get Mechanize Links
                    for l,lt in zip(levelLinks,linkText):
                        print newurl,"\n",lt,"\n"


        except:
            urls.pop(0)
```

it gets results like that:

```
http://www.adbnews.com/area51/contact.html 
CONTACT 

http://www.adbnews.com/area51/about.html 
ABOUT 

http://www.adbnews.com/area51/index.html 
INDEX 

http://www.adbnews.com/area51/1st/ 
FIRST LEVEL! 

http://www.adbnews.com/area51/1st/bling.html 
BLING 

http://www.adbnews.com/area51/1st/index.html 
INDEX 

http://adbnews.com/area51/2nd/ 
2ND LEVEL
```

And I wanna add a counter of somekind which could limit how deep crawler goes..

I've tried add for example `steps = 3` and change `while i<len(urls)` in `while i<steps:`

but that would go only to first level even the number says 3...

Any advice is welcome

Comment: Just to check: are you aware of the Opensource project [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) - to save you re-inventing the wheel on this...

Comment: is scrapy good when you wanna get links from multiple sites? In this example I'm getting link from only one url but in reality I have several addresses to scrap

Comment: It's highly configurable... just tell it allowed domains and stuff, how many spiders, etc... etc... if you want to do it properly, and aren't afraid of a small learning curve, I'd put your time into going through some basic examples and learning it...

Comment: Will check it out, but now I'm short with some time limits on job so I must go with this code...

Comment: fair enough, but I have a strange feeling that by the time you've restructured your code to accommodate what you want to do, you'd have been able to do it already ;) Good luck though...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search a certain "depth", consider using a recursive function instead of just appending a list of URL's.

```
def crawl(url, depth):
  if depth <= 3:
    #Scan page, grab links, title
    for link in links:
      print crawl(link, depth + 1)
  return url +"\n"+ title
```

This allows for easier control of your recursive searching, as well as being faster and less resource heavy :)

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly should I put this recursive function in my program... I'm a bit of nooby in python so I'm getting strugle with a lots of errors. Could you write it out in http://pastebin.com for example?